# Parallel programming for all R packages

Tags: r, parallel-processing

Do you know if there are any plans to introduce parallel programming in R for all packages? 
I'm aware of some developments such as R-revolution and parallel programming packages, but they seem to have specialised functions which replace the most popular functions (linear programming etc..). However one of the great things about R is the huge amount of specialised packages which prop up every day and make complex and time-consuming analysis very easy to run. Many of these use very popular functions such as the generalised linear model, but also use the results for additional calculation and comparison and finally sort out the output. As far as I understand you need to define which parts of a function can be run in parallel programming so this is probably why most specialised R packages don't have this functionality and cannot have it unless the code is edited.

Are there are any plans (or any packages) to enable all the most popular R functions to run in parallel processing so that all the less popular functions containing these can be run in parallel processing? For example, the package difR uses the glm function for most of its functions; if the glm package was enabled to run in parallel processing (or re-written and then released in a new R version) for all multi-processor machines then there would be no need to re-write the difR package and this could then run some of its most burdensome procedures with the aid of parallel programming on a Windows PC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I completely agree with Paul's answer.

In addition, a general system for parallelization needs some very non-trivial calibration, even for those functions that can be easily parallelized: What if you have a call stack of several functions that offer parallel computation (e.g. you are bootstrapping some model fitting, the model fitting may already offer parallelization and low level linear algebra can be implicitly parallel)? You need to estimate (or choose manually) at which level explicit parallelization should be done. In addition, you possibly have implicit parallelization, so you need to trade off between these.

However, there is one particularly easy and general way to parallelize computations implicitly in R: linear algebra can be parallelized and sped up considerably by using an optimized BLAS. Using this can (depending on your system) be as easy as telling your package manager to install the optimized BLAS and R will use it. Once it is linked to R, all packages that use the base linear algebra functions like `%*%`, `crossprod`, `solve` etc. will profit.

See e.g. Dirk Eddelbüttel's `gcbd` package and its vignette, and also discussions how to use GotoBLAS2 / OpenBLAS.

Answer (score 2):

How to parallelize a certain problem is often non-trivial. Therefore, a specific implementation has to be made in each and every case, in this case for each R package. So, I do not think a general implementation of parallel processing in R will be made, or is even possible.